# Delphi ClientDataSet - Delete Operation - Why is it so slow?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I'm using TClientDataSet in an application for managing a load of data imported from multiple CSV files. This can be a million or more entries in total. I want to be able to delete all the dataset entries associated with a particular CSV file but the time to delete large numbers of items is cripplingly slow.

As a test to try and work out if I was doing something stupid I created a simple console application. All it does is:

- Create a TClientDataSet instance with 1 field defined (ID):

  `CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
   CDS.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger);
   CDS.CreateDataSet;
   CDS.LogChanges := False;`
- Append 100,000 items (takes 0.1 seconds):

  `for i := 1 to 100000 do
   begin
    CDS.AppendRecord([i]);
   end;`
- Delete 50,000 items (takes ~4 secs, or ~4.4 secs with `LogChanges=TRUE`):

  `CDS.First;
   while CDS['ID'] <= 50000 do
    CDS.Delete;`

If I had 1.5M items in my dataset and wanted to remove 0.5M entries it would take so long to delete items by this method that I can't even measure it.

As a workaround for now I'm having to create a new dataset, then copy all the items that I want to keep to the new copy and delete the original copy. Unless I am only removing a small % of entries from the original dataset this method is much faster.

Perhaps I am not using the most appropriate method for trying to remove items from the dataset? I am guessing it is triggering a bunch of internal processing with every item I delete. Is there some method to delete a range of items at once that I am missing? Perhaps I can set an index and a range based on that index, and then delete all the items in the current range with one operation?

Maybe the problem is with ClientDataSet and not me? Perhaps I need to use a different component. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to turn off [`LogChanges`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.LogChanges).

Comment: Interesting, there should be a difference as maintaining the delta isn't cheap.

Comment: As you mentioned aggregates and indexes, these may be the culprit; try to disable them before the bulk delete operation and re-enable them (if needed) after. (The problem might be that they are updated after every single delete which is completely unnecessary.)

Comment: The test console app I used doesn't do anything extra than the code listed above except for measuring speed, so no indexes defined other than the default index or aggregates. In emb documentation they state that defined indexes should make no impact at all until they are actually applied anyway. [I'll update the question again to avoid the confusing mention of indexes/aggs.]

Comment: I made a mistake before. Turning off LogChanges as you both mentioned did make a significant improvement (~30 secs to ~10 secs) however this is still 10 seconds to delete half the items as opposed to < 1 second to add the items in the first place.

Comment: I think that is expected. Deleting requires moving data in the file.

Comment: Perhaps - but I would love to know if I am missing some method for deleting a block of items in one go. Maybe the dataset has (or should have?) some method for marking a large range of items for deletion, and then deleting then all at once and juggling the memory allocations around in 1 sweep?

Comment: Try comparing the time required to delete from the back.

Comment: Using almost identical code (I added a TStopWatch to do the timing, and changed `Append/Set/Post` with `CDS.AddRecord([I]);`, I get 73ms to add 100000 rows and 3883ms (3.9 seconds) to delete the first 50000.

Comment: the problem is with midas implementation. depending on midas version it can be slower or faster and bring different bugs. in my test with my own cds/midas implementation I get less than 3 seconds to delete 50k records with either enabled delta or disabled delta and cds.Capacity (one of my own extensions) set. try to test another component, for example kbmmt

Comment: Which version of Delphi? Have you tried Andreas Hausladen's MidasSpeedFix?

Comment: @Craig: I gave it a go (using CDS.Last; while CDS['ID'] > 50000 do CDS.Delete;). If anything, it was a little slower!

Comment: @Ken: Thanks for the `CDS.APPENDRECORD([I])` tip. That was definitely a little faster than using `Append/Set/Post` for adding items.

Comment: @Ondrej: XE9 (Seattle). I don't think MidasSpeedFix applies? I can't compile with version 1.2 added to project anyway.

Comment: I think I had something weird going on with power settings to give me that ~10 second delete time before. I'm rerunning the test now without changing anything and getting 110 ms to add, 3980 ms to delete. Very much in line with Ken's times. With Craig's suggestion interestingly (delete the last 50k items) I'm getting ~5250 to delete, although it isn't really a relevant option when applied to my real application anyway. The block of records to be deleted can be positioned anywhere.

Comment: @vavan: I tested TkbmMemTable just now and got 80ms/1440ms, some improvement! I know nothing about the component though and documentation doesn't seem readily available for the trial version. Maybe there are more efficient ways of using it?  There is still this big gap between adding items and removing them though. Which is still a problem in my application where a user might add their data in 10 seconds, and then have to wait 10 minutes to remove some of it. In the end, the alternative option of just copying all the records you with to keep to a new dataset still wins.

Comment: @PhilB Do these blocks of records that you delete always contain same records that were added from a specific CSV file? If yes then you might be better of by creating separate Data Set for each CSV file and creating a custom class which will allow you to edit/search amongst all of the records as they were all part of the same database table. Something similar to relational databases. This way you would avoid any need for reorganizing records in memory after block of them gets deleted. ...

Comment: ... Also you get possibility for multithreaded searches where each data set can have its own thread doing the searching.

Comment: @Silver: Nice suggestion. Yes, the delete operation is always about removing all the entries corresponding to a specific CSV file, and the dataset might contain 10+ different CSV files of different size/shape. Some of them might have overlapping data e.g. corresponds to the same information, but updated values.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I might as well provide details of my own (temporary/maybe permanent?) workaround in case anyone with the same problem is interested.

PROBLEM: Delete a large proportion of records from a large TClientDataSet (100k or more records) takes a long time when using the Delete operation in comparison to initial time for adding the items (factor of 40 or more).

SOLUTION: Copy all the records you do not wish to delete to a new dataset, then delete the original. [Downsides: Loss of changelog, extra RAM requirements?]

```
var
 CDS: TClientDataSet;

// initialize new CDS instance
function CreateNewCDSInstance: TCLientDataSet;
begin
 Result := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
 Result.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger);
 Result.CreateDataSet;
 Result.LogChanges := False;
end;

// close + free CDS instance
procedure CloseCDS;
begin
 CDS.EmptyDataSet;
 CDS.Close;
 CDS.Free;
end;

// delete current record?
function CanDeleteCurrentRecord: boolean;
begin
 Result := CDS['ID'] < 50001; //in this simple example
 // in my application it would be more like:
 // "CDS['FILE_ID'] = AFileIDToDelete"
end;

// delete block of records:
procedure DeleteRecords;
var
 aNewCopy: TClientDataSet;
begin
 aNewCopy := CreateNewCDSInstance;
 CDS.First;
 while not CDS.EoF do
 begin
  if not CanDeleteCurrentRecord then
  begin
   // NB: AppendRecord takes array of values corresponding to field defintions
   aNewCopy.AppendRecord([CDS['ID']]);
  end;
  CDS.Next;
 end;
 CloseCDS;
 CDS := aNewCopy;
 //NB: If you have any aggregates/indexes defined, they must be redefined
end;
```

Using the example given above this method of removing 50k items takes 94 ms instead of ~4 secs.

However, while asking this question and reading through the comments it has become obvious to me that this solution is more of a bandage than a cure. The bigger problem is that the system I'm working on isn't really well designed to handle the amount of data it needs to. Perhaps it is not so much "problem with TClientDataSet" as "problem with how we're using TClientDataSet"! Even with the fix for delete speed there will still be issues with performance for importing increasingly large size and quantity of files and managing that data down the line.

Perhaps (on a rainy day!) I will start looking at an approach akin to SilverWarior's suggestion of using a separate dataset to hold each imported file, instead of splurging all the data out into one huge memory table. Then deleting a file just becomes deleting the dataset - among other potential benefits.